# How to calculate total amount in ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, ionic3, addition

I'm trying to count total amount where amount take place in diff cards. I tried below code but it gives me wrong output as when i enter amount as a 10 and again i enter amount 20 then it gives me 1020 as an output.

```
 this.itemCount = this.bindlcdetails.length;
   this.totalamount=0;
   for(let i = 0; i<this.bindlcdetails.length; i++){
    this.totalamount = this.totalamount + this.amount; 
  }
  return this.totalamount;
```

where bindlcdetails is a number of cards where information and amount takes place and at the end calculate total amount

Update:
       I updated the expected output from img

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output? Add some example info like `bindlcdetails.length = 50`

Comment: i tried this one also but not working and my expected output is when i enter amount first as 10 and when i again add details with amount 20 then total amount will be 30

Comment: `this.amount?`, `this` is not for `for` loop, if `this.amount` is not a part of loop then do not use loop you can simply use  `this.totalamount = this.bindlcdetails.length * this.amount;`. Please expose in details what you want.

Comment: please check my answer @PradnyaBhagat

Answer (score 0):

> Need to change in following manner:

```
 this.itemCount = this.bindlcdetails.length;
 return (this.amount * this.itemCount);
```